# How do I get the next element's text for all h2 elements using xpath?

Tags: html, xpath, scrapy

I have HTML that looks like the following.

```
<div class="topics">
<h2>Topics 1</h2>
News
Sports
<h2>Topics 2</h2>
Entertainment
Business
</div>
```

I want to be able to get the text `["News\nSports", "Entertainment\nBusiness"]` using `XPath`. How do I do this?

`//div[contains(@class,"topics")]/h2/text()` gives me the `h2` text, but I also want the corresponding (the following) text below as well.

`//div[contains(@class,"topics")]/h2/following-sibling::text()` does give me all the text after `h2` but in a pattern like this this array `["News", "\n", "Sports", "Entertainment", "\n", "Business"]`. There is now no way I can associate the array of text strings back to the header.

I'm using [Scrapy v1.5.1](https://scrapy.org/) to issue the XPath.

```
content.xpath("//div[contains(@class,"topics")]/h2/following-sibling::text()").extract()
```

The strange thing is that this XPath query works in Chrome (viewing the yellow highlighted text), but not via Scrapy.

Comment: `>>> sel.xpath('//div[contains(@class,"topics")]/h2/following-sibling::text()').extract()`
`['\nNews\nSports\n', '\nEntertainment\nBusiness\n']` works for me; are you quite literally using `content.xpath("...,"topics"...")` because if so, that's not even legal python

Comment: ^ Exactly the same result for me. Besides problem with quotes, this expression works fine and gives `[u'\nNews\nSports\n', u'\nEntertainment\nBusiness\n']`

Comment: The example above wasn't faithful to the real situation. The real file had weird characters that caused breaks. In beautifulsoup, these characters are rendered as br tags, but in scrapy new line characters. I decided to use beautifulsoup to parse just this part of the HTML. Thanks for verifying.